# Disable dates in the past in datepicker

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datepicker

Here I have implemented the code which disables previous dates of current date in "start date "datepicker and disables previous dates of chosen "start date" in "end date" datepicker. it was working very well but all of the sudden it does not  disable  previous dates of current date in "start date "datepicker.

view:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="pwd">Start Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id='Sdate' name='Sdate' min="" value="">
  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Sdate'); ?></div>

</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-4">
  <label for="pwd">End Date</label>
  <input type="date" class="form-control" id='Edate' name='Edate' value="<?php echo set_value('Edate'); ?>">
  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Edate'); ?></div>
</div>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 var today = new Date();
 var sdate = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+(today.getDate() < 10 ? '0'+today.getDate() : today.getDate());
 $('#Sdate').prop('min', sdate);

 $('#Sdate').on('change', function(){
    $('#Edate').prop('min', $(this).val() );
 });

});
```

Comment: this works very well, once you fix the typo: missing `})`; to close `$(document).ready(function(){`. see https://jsfiddle.net/b4dp0mnL/

Comment: Its not missing in my original code, I just missed that here since I didn't need to include all the codes:) , it is still not working , even in the jsfiddle that you shared its not working.@Vickel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your variable `sdate` returns '2021-1-11' but should be '2021-01-11'

just change your code slightly, to add a leading `0`for all month <10

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  const options1 = {
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'numeric',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  var today = new Date();
  y = today.getFullYear()
  m = today.getMonth() + 1
  m = m < 10 ? '0' + m : m;
  d = today.getDate()
  d = d < 10 ? '0' + d : d;
  sdate = y + '-' + m + '-' + d

  $('#Sdate').prop('min', sdate);

  $('#Sdate').on('change', function() {
    $('#Edate').prop('min', $(this).val());
  });
});
```

see a [working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vyz0tow1/) here, dates in the past are now disabled